# queryset values() with annotate() not behaving as documented

Tags: python, django, orm

Unless I've misinterpreted [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses), it says that if you do, e.g., `query_set.values('name').annotate(votes=Sum('vote'))`, the ORM would group rows with the same `name` and apply `Sum('vote')` to each group.  However, I keep getting a result set where rows with the same name are not being aggregated; they are being returned as separate entries in the result set.  Have I misread [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses)?

I'm on Django 1.8.

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: Should you be using `aggregate` and not `annotate`?

Comment: [Rod Xavier](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1134851/rod-xavier) I don't believe `aggregate` interacts with `values` in the same way (or at least it's not documented)...  [ozgur](http://stackoverflow.com/users/793428/ozgur) my models are fairly complex but I'm working on posting something

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misread your question. Have you tried using `order_by`. I think you should order the queryset first by `name` before calling `annotate`.

Comment: Actually if your model has a default `ordering`, you should neutralize its effect by calling `order_by` with no parameters. Because parameters used in `order_by` are put in `values()` call  which in turn make identical rows appear to be separate. So you should do `query_set.values('name').annotate(votes=Sum('vote')).order_by()`